# What are the most recommended guide/maps to bring on a PCT thru-hike?

Tags: hiking, preparation, resources, thru-hike, pacific-crest-trail

Among the amalgam of guidebooks and maps for the [Pacific Crest Trail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pacific_Crest_Trail), which guidebooks and/or maps are be the best contenders to bring on the trail?

[Guthook 2010 review](http://www.guthookhikes.com/2010/11/myth-5-the-best-guidebook-for-the-pct-is.html) is no longer available. It recommended [Halfmile maps](http://www.pctmap.net/), which is still available in March, 2018, combined with [PocketPCT](http://hikethru.com/pocket_pct/pocket-pct), which is not available.  However, [postholer maps](http://postholer.com/mapbooks/index.php?trail_id=1) are not considered in his review.

Guthook provided an excellent answer to this question. Since it's no longer available, there's no way to know if it still holds true.

Comment: ppl -- As you can see with Guthook, the problem with this sort of question is the short shelf life.  A correct answer today will likely be incorrect by next year.

Comment: You could perhaps change your question to focus on what resources are available and then future readers can decide for themselves what's best. Still a bit of a time-sensitivity, but not nearly like that of your question's current form.

Answer (score 2):

I have used the listed below website for as long as they have been around.  They provide very detailed and regularly updated maps from the national survey association.  I recommend getting a lamination machine and printing off these maps that are along the trail just before leaving for your trip.  The weight is no more than carrying the Guthook book.

http://market.weogeo.com/?lat=41.5507&lon=-84.8867&zoom=8&layers=BT&page=1

Here is a quick video about the site.

http://www.weogeo.com/support/WeoGeo_Basics.html

I have also never had any issues from them for viruses or malware.