# Is there an equivalent of "The A.T. Guide" for the Pacific Crest Trail?

Tags: hiking, preparation, thru-hike, books, pacific-crest-trail

I'm asking on behalf of my roommates who want to hike the Pacific Crest Trail. We all recently moved to San Diego from the East Coast, and they're trying to find a book as informative and detailed as *The A.T. Guide*, but having trouble, online as well as perusing through several bookstores here in San Diego. Would anyone have any suggestions? Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several equivalents just as there is for the AT. I would consider  **Halfmile maps** combined with **PocketPCT**.

- [Halfmile's PCT maps](http://www.pctmap.net/)
- ['Erik the Black' books](http://blackwoodspress.com/pacific-crest-trail/maps/atlas/)
- [PCT Data Book](http://shop.pcta.org/publications/pacific-crest-trail-data-book/)
- [Pocket PCT](http://hikethru.com/pocket_pct) (No longer available at this link as of March 2018)
- [U.S. Forest Service PCT](http://shop.pcta.org/trail-maps/)
- [Yogi's](http://www.pcthandbook.com/) (No longer available as of March of 2018)
- [Wilderness Press](https://www.wildernesspress.com/authors.php?authorid=313) books / databook ('*official*')

The [PCTA](http://www.pcta.org/) also [provides a listing](http://www.pcta.org/discover-the-trail/maps-and-guidebooks/), which is no longer at that page, as of March, 2018, and [sells books](http://shop.pcta.org/books/). Guthook had a [review on his blog](http://www.guthookhikes.com/2010/11/myth-5-the-best-guidebook-for-the-pct-is.html), which is no longer available as of March 2018.

I would also add that while maps are not as popular on the AT they are most common on the PCT. Postholer have the nicest maps but Halfmile maps sometimes include useful comments which are a plus.

As for which one's you should bring with you, this is [an entirely different question](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/3961/what-are-the-most-recommended-guide-maps-to-bring-on-a-pct-thru-hike).

*P.S. Feel free to edit/add more guidebooks*

Comment: Hi ppl! Your links to Yogi's and Guthook are dead, as is the list from the PCTA that you mentioned. I've noted the dead links in the question rather than deleting them, just to let people know that these things were there but aren't any more. You might want to look at all the PCTlinks. Some just go to the front page of the Pacific Coast Trail Association shopping page. Your other post that you linked to also has some dead links, so I'll note those over there.

Answer (score 3):

As of 2017, the majority of PCT thru-hikers are relying on apps. The most popular option is known as "Guthook," from Atlas Guides. Other popular options include "Halfmile" and "Hikerbot."

These apps are comparable to AWOL's AT guidebook in many ways. While offerings vary between apps, you can expect to find a GPS route of the trail, elevation profiles, locations of campsites, and detailed listings of resupply town resources.